# Filing UIBezierPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I color the inside of the UIBezier path? I am making a simple triangle and want to color inside of the triangle with red color.

```
class GraphView : UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

       UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        UIColor.greenColor().setStroke()

        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(100,620))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(300,100))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(500,620))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(100,620))

        path.closePath()

        path.fill()
        path.stroke()

    }

}


let graphView = GraphView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,960,640))
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = graphView
```

The above code is written in the playground: Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Opps sorry! Updated the question with code and new screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you're creating your `UIBezierPath`. You're creating it with a rectangle of the view's bounds, and then adding a triangle inside that rectangle. Therefore they're both getting filled – resulting in the entire view being red.

If you set `usesEvenOddFillRule` to `true`, you'll better see the result of the unwanted rectangle in your path:

[image]

If you just want to fill a triangle then replace this line:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
```

with this:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
```

This will create a new *empty* `UIBezierPath` that you can add your triangle to.

Comment: Thanks! One thing that bugs me is that even if I omit the last line: path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(100,620)) it still creates the triangle. Does it not require that last line to complete the triangle.

Comment: @johndoe `path.closePath()` will create the triangle by joining the last point of the path with the first point of the path (with a straight line) – so therefore that last line is indeed redundant. Also note that `path.fill()` will [implicitly close the path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/fill).